# Centering multiple items within a CSS Grid Container?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In this demo there are two divs within the css grid container div.  Is it possible to center them so that the second item sits within and on top of the first item and both are centered vertically and horizontally?  I thought perhaps `align-self` would do it ...

```html
<div
  style="
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
  "
>
  <div
    style="
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      align-self: center;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      align-self: center;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: yellow;
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place them on the same area (`grid-area:1/1`) and use `place-self` to align them vertically and horizontally.

```html
<div
  style="
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
  "
>
  <div
    style="
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      place-self: center;
      grid-area: 1/1
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: yellow;
      place-self: center;
      grid-area: 1/1
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply center divisions inside divisions via adding

```
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
```

attributes to main container. So this will work:

```html
<div style=" display: grid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;">
  <div style=" display: grid;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;">
    <div style="
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: yellow;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works indeed.  I'm hoping there is a way to do it without nesting the containers within each other ...

Comment: It's for when content is inserted dynamically ... and all the items should overlap each other and. be centered ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to centre the two  elements within the CSS grid container so that the second item sits within and on top of the first item, and both are centred vertically and horizontally. The `align-self: center;` and `justify-self: center;` properties can be used.

```html
<div
  style="
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative; /* Added to create a positioning context */
  "
>
  <div
    style="
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      align-self: center;
      justify-self: center;
      position: relative; /* Added to create a positioning context */
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      align-self: center;
      justify-self: center;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: yellow;
      position: absolute; /* Positioned absolutely within the parent */
      top: 50%; /* Move 50% down from the top */
      left: 50%; /* Move 50% from the left */
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Center the item */
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```

I've added the following changes:

- `justify-self: center;` has been added to both `<div>` elements to centre them horizontally within the grid cell.
- `position: relative;` has been added to both `<div>` elements to create a positioning context for the absolute positioning of the inner `<div>`.
- For the inner yellow `<div>`, `position: absolute;` is used to position it absolutely within the parent container.
- `top: 50%; and left: 50%;` are used to position the yellow `<div>` 50% down from the top and 50% from the left, which places its top left corner at the centre of the parent.
- `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` is used to shift the yellow `<div>` half of its width and height to centre it perfectly within the parent.

With these adjustments, the two `<div>` elements will be centred both vertically and horizontally, and the second item will sit within and on top of the first item.

Comment: This is close.  I was hoping there was a way to do it with just pure grid parameters so that we would not have to rely on absolute positioning ...

Answer (score -1):

You can try it

```html
  

 <div
      style="
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
        align-items: center;
        justify-items: center;
      "
    >
      <div
        style="
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr;
          grid-template-rows: 1fr;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background-color: red;
          justify-items: center;
        "
        >
          <div
            style="
              width: 50px;
              height: 50px;
              background-color: yellow;
              align-self: center;
            "
            ></div>
      </div>
</div>
```